# Exception while getting string from conf file in Play 2 with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, typesafe-config

I am trying to get a file path from conf, this is my conf file:

uploadedFilePath.conf

```
file.path="public/img/"
```

This is how I am getting path from conf file in my code:

```
     val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
     var path : String = conf.getString("file.path")
```

I am getting exception on second line

> 09:58:11.527 108649 [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10]
>   PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler ERROR - Cannot invoke the action
>   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path
>   has type OBJECT rather than STRING
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:159)
>   ~[com.typesafe.config-1.3.0.jar:na]
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
>   ~[com.typesafe.config-1.3.0.jar:na]
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
>   ~[com.typesafe.config-1.3.0.jar:na]
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
>   ~[com.typesafe.config-1.3.0.jar:na]
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:246)
>   ~[com.typesafe.config-1.3.0.jar:na]

I am do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes

```
file.path=public/img/
```